# How generate ansible_ssh_private_key_file for openshift inventory?

Tags: ansible, openshift, ansible-2.x

I'm using Ansible 2.4 and Installing Openshift 3.6 in an already pre-installed cloud environment with multiple machines.

I'm aware that I should pass:

`ansible_ssh_private_key_file=filename.pem` to the inventory file, as well 'ansible_ssh_user' . But till now I've not found anything clear article that show how should I generate this `ssh_private_key_file`.

Current variable:

```
ansible_user=root
```

Comment: Is the cloud environment AWS? This file will be the .pem selected when the instances were launched. LEts put this another way, how do you currently ssh to the machines in the cluster?

Comment: No it's not. It's a private cloud the environment is on Ravello.

Comment: Ok and how do you currently ssh to the vms in that environment?

Comment: using directly ssh that apparently is already defined. As I just do 'ssh master1.example.com'

Answer (score 0):

[`ssh-keygen`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) generates private keys for SSH. The option `-m` can be used to specify the `PEM` format during export.

First generate the key:

```
ssh-keygen -f mykey
```

And then export public in PEM format:

```
ssh-keygen -e -m PEM -f mykey.pub
```

Comment: How will that help to provision the cluster though? I think op might be missing the actual point here so generating an ssh key which will not allow Ansible to ssh to those nodes isn't really going to achieve anything.